# Nginx not able to fetch files in /location alias

Tags: nginx

my server.conf config is simple:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/sipml5;
    location /well-known/ {
     alias /tmp/tmp/;
   }
}
```

There is file named "test.txt" inside /tmp/tmp/test.text

However when i point my browser to http:///well-known/test.txt, i get error 404

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OS might treat `/tmp` in a special way, so that every user has its own `/tmp` directory. Therefore, since nginx runs as `www-data` or similar user, it cannot see the file you have created using your own account.

Please try some directory under `/var/www` instead.